# How do you make sonic booms quieter

Tags: supersonic, passenger

I was looking through several sources and I can’t find anything explaining **how sonic booms can be muted**. In the [Lockheed Martin Quesst](https://www.nasa.gov/mission/quesst/) experimental airplane info it states that it supposedly has a “whoomph” instead of a “boom” sound, which makes it quieter. Can someone explain how this actually happens? How do you change the sound and volume of the sonic boom? [Here is an article about the project.](https://www.mobilityengineeringtech.com/component/content/article/adt/stories/news/43882)

Comment: You use  the X-59 [Quiet SuperSonic Technology](https://www.nasa.gov/centers-and-facilities/armstrong/taming-the-boom/)?

Answer (score 3):

The best ways to reduce sonic boom is to reduce the volume and mass of the aircraft.  After that, you can work on shaping the aircraft to change the characteristics of the boom.

The boom sound comes from a pressure wave passing over the observer after the aircraft flies overhead.

Although an aircraft is a complex shape that may have many shocks and expansions in its flow-field, far from the aircraft the initial shocks tend co coalesce into one strong shock, followed by a gradual expansion, followed by a final shock at the end of the aircraft.  This is called an N-wave.

This N-wave is the classical shape of a strong boom.  The characteristic of the noise (intensity and tone) are largely determined by how high the initial pressure peak is and how quickly it is achieved.

[image: Simple boom theory diagram] [Figure from this paper.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239535155_Multiobjective_Conceptual_Studies_For_Aerospace_Design_IMA_Mathematical_Modeling_Workshop_2007)

If we can reduce the initial peak and lengthen the pressure rise time, we can reduce the boom.  This usually requires working to prevent the shocks from coalescing together.

Answer (score 0):

The volume: you reduce the area which cause the boom, so less air displaced per area and so less pressure (so volume). A small meteorite has less volume compared a larger one. i assume that engines and other less aerodynamic parts are more sensible to make louder boom. Note: the sound is difference on pressure, one may also do destructive waves (with some phase difference).

The sound: you create the boom at different times (e.g. in various parts of the wings, with some time difference, e.g. 1/5 second or longer).

How? It is tricky (and not a supersonic engineer). I assume that with new materials, we may get some slight design on aircraft surface, which has minimal aerodynamic effect, but which can reduce supersonic boom.

Comment: "*How? It is tricky*", some ideas in [Review of Sonic Boom Prediction and Reduction Methods for Next Generation of Supersonic Aircraft](https://www.mdpi.com/2226-4310/10/11/917). It's tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by flying at the maximum altitude possible. This will dilute the shock energy over the largest possible area on the ground.

Comment: That can help but it still can be pretty loud for people directly under the flight path, like in [this video](https://youtu.be/_XKfBfmg5I4?si=hG_076afGLbkW7i5) taken on a ship as Concorde passed overhead. Supersonic aircraft could possibly follow routes that avoid direct overflights of major cities, but at some point a zig-zag pattern will become inefficient and there are going to be inevitable direct flyovers.

Comment: @StevePemberton, agree on all points. My personal feeling is nobody *needs* to travel at supersonic speeds in a passenger plane in the first place: no SST's means lots less sonic booms.

Comment: nielsnielsen - I think we will probably see Mach 1.2 business jets. From what I have read the methods being developed to reduce sonic boom levels only work up to about that speed. There is supposed to be a multi-month test creating booms of this level over a U.S. city to gauge public acceptance. Mach 1.2 is not fast enough to make the cost worthwhile for airline use, but is a decent speed improvement that probably many business travelers would be willing to pay for. For bragging rights if nothing else. I suspect many people flew Concorde just to brag about it not to save time.

Comment: @StevePemberton yes yes indeed, and there will always be people with enough money that the costs are immaterial. How do airplanes stay up in the air? Money, and the bernoulli effect. -NN

Comment: Although not enough people with money to support supersonic airline travel, as evidenced by Concorde. Of course it was limited because of overland speed restrictions as well as relatively short range, the only practical regular route being between east coast U.S. and western Europe (not counting charter flights). But even at its peak it only flew three scheduled flights per day each way across the Atlantic, which is about 600 passengers per day.  But business jets have a different business model, and especially with fractional use there are plenty of people with enough money to fly supersonic.